# Is Inner SELF JOIN the right tool for this two-step filtering?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

Some context, I am using postgres and I have a table that has items defined something like this:

```sql
CREATE TYPE EventType AS ENUM ('published', 'unpublished');

CREATE TABLE items (
    id          integer NOT NULL,
    name        varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    event       EventType NOT NULL,
    date        date
);
```

The critical thing to realize here is that name is not necessarily unique, so something could be published with a name on date X, then get unpublished on date Y, then republished again on date Z. Given any particular contiguous `[published, unpublished)` for a given `name`, these will be associated with each other by sharing the same `id`. The only constraint is that there won't be overlapping `[published, unpublished)` ranges with the same `name` in the database. You can thus imagine this as representing a list of "in-existence ranges" for a given  `name`. Usually any `id` will have a `published` and `unpublished` entry, *except* for the most recent `published` one, which may not yet have an `unpublished` entry. You can imagine this as representing `[published, ?)`.

As such, the goal is to, given a specified `QUERY_DATE` and `name`, return the `id` that represents the range it falls under (`QUERY_DATE >= published && QUERY_DATE < unpublished`), and taking into account the special case where (`QUERY_DATE >= published and there is no "unpublished entry").

A separate representation you could imagine for this (which would admittedly make my problem much easier to solve, but I am not in control of this data), is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE items (
    id              integer NOT NULL,
    name            varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    published       date NOT NULL,
    unpublished     date
);
```

Here the above query would be fairly straight-forward, you would just do:

```sql
SELECT id FROM items
    WHERE
        name = THE_NAME AND
        published <= QUERY_DATE AND 
        (unpublished = NULL OR unpublished > QUERY_DATE)
```

However, we don't have the above schema, we have the separated range one from before. If I break this up into two queries, it is conceptually simple (pseudo-code below). Given that the date ranges are known to not overlap, we can just first ask for the LATEST matching published item, and then we just need to do a quick check at the end to make sure it wasn't unpublished. But I am still doing two queries:

```js
const lastPublishedAfterDateID = query(`
    SELECT id FROM items
    WHERE
        name = ${name} AND
        event = published AND
        published <= ${date}
    ORDERED DESCENDING
    LIMIT 1`));

const isUnpublished = query(`
    SELECT id FROM items
    WHERE
        id = ${lastPublishedAfterDateID} AND
        event = unpublished AND
        unpublished > ${date}`);

const result = isUnpublished ? null : lastPublishedAfterDateID;
```

I *think* there is an alternative way to accomplish this all in the query by doing an INNER SELF JOIN. Something like:

```sql
SELECT id
    FROM items AS published
    LEFT JOIN items AS unpublished
    WHERE
        published.name = THE_NAME AND
        published.type = published AND
        published.date <= QUERY_DATE AND
        
        unplublished.id = published.id AND
        unpublished.type = unpublished AND
        unpublished.date > QUERY_DATE
    LIMIT 1
```

I think they limit 1 might be superfluous here, since there'd only ever be one unless that data in the table is incorrect. The LEFT JOIN handles the case of no end date. Either way, I *think* the above might get me the equivalent to the two-step process above, but it's not clear to me whether this is horribly inefficient or not idiomatic/etc. Conceptually this is simple to explain "Give me the LATEST item whose publish date is before the given date, unless it also falls after the unpublished date, in which case just return null". Again, if I was in control of the data, I would just be trying to make my life easier with the second schema I posted, but I am not.

Comment: Hi - it would probably be a lot simpler if you just provided enough sample data to illustrate the possible scenarios and the result you want to achieve based on that data

Comment: I think the basic problem here is that you're working with event-driven architecture, but you're querying the events rather than the results of an aggregator. Your query for "this is how it should work" is indeed how this should work... set an aggregator on the events and build a table that can be queried as you suggested. Windowed functions will indeed work here, as will breaking down the steps into a chain of common table expressions, two queries, temporary objects, or a host of other solutions that effectively get round the fact that materialising the data is the real problem here

Answer (score 1):

Window functions could be the way:

```
select ID, name, event, date from 
(select ID, name, event, date,
LEAD(date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date) next_date
   from items) e
where QUERY_DATE >= date and ( QUERY_DATE < next_date  or next_date is null)
and name = THE_NAME;
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/7736)

Answer (score 0):

I like how you can translate this into a [`not exists`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) pretty much word-for-word: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/oVx5jSc6)

```sql
select distinct on(name)*     --"Give me the LATEST
from  items p                 -- item
where p.event='published'     -- whose publish
and   p.date<='2023-03-06'    -- date is before the given date,
and not exists (              -- unless
    select true
    from   items u
    where u.name = p.name     -- it
    and u.id   = p.id           
    and u.date>= p.date       -- also 
    and u.date < '2023-03-06' -- falls after 
    and u.event='unpublished' -- the unpublished date"
    )
and   p.name='Matrix'         -- (given a specified QUERY_DATE **and name**)
order by name,date desc;--this selects the the latest as the distinct one to return
```

1. Determine bound inclusivity: it's not clear whether a name unpublished exactly on the `QUERY_DATE` should be considered already unpublished as of the date, or still published until the end of it.
2. If your ID's are in ascending order following the progression of `date` and you're only after the ID, you can swap out [`distinct on()...order by`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) for a `max(id)`. Your pseudocode `SELECT id FROM...ORDERED DESCENDING LIMIT 1` would suggest that would be the case.
3. When there's nothing matching your criteria, it returns no rows, which is not the same as returning a row with a `null`.